# Why is SignalR throwing an error that doesn't provide any information?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, .net-4.8, asp.net-core-signalr

Getting below errors in SignalR.

It should not throw any errors. We are not getting any Error messages. It only says Error. But what not about what error occurred?

[image]

> Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': Error: There was an
> error with the transport. Error: Failed to start the transport
> 'ServerSentEvents': Error: Error occurred Error: Connection
> disconnected with error 'Error'. Error: Failed to start the transport
> 'LongPolling': Error signalr.js:4741 WebSocket connection to
> 'wss://tst.com/SignalRHub?id=ujZbbgfwN2nbPvjGTIpGBw' failed:
> [2023-05-22T12:36:24.679Z] Error: Failed to start the connection:
> Error: Unable to connect to the server with any of the available
> transports. WebSockets failed: Error: There was an error with the
> transport. ServerSentEvents failed: Error: Error occurred LongPolling
> failed: Error

```
new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(window.location.origin+\"/SignalRHub\", { skipNegotiations: true})
  .withAutomaticReconnect([0, 0, 10000])
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
  .build()
```

All errors are coming at the same time.

It should not throw any errors.

Comment: it says 404 Not Found for the endpoint - `https://{host}/SignalRHub?id=xxxxx` Does this endpoint exist and is available for the frontend application?

Comment: Yes, It is exist and sometime it works. But refreshing mutliple times it is throwing an error.

Comment: Does this webapp have multiple servers? Where you host this app, azure or ?

Comment: Which SignalR and ASP.NET version are you *actually* using? ASP.NET Core doesn't run on .NET Framework 4.8 at all. .NET Framework has an old version of SignalR that's in maintenance mode. In .NET Core/ASP.NET Core SignalR was completely redesigned because the old architecture didn't scale well. All new features and fixes go to ASP.NET Core SignalR. The ASP.NET Framework SignalR packages get only maintenance releases and [haven't had a release for over a year](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR)

Comment: The log contains a *lot* of information. It says that the SignalR client tried to connect using all available methods, WebSockets, Server-Sent Events and Long Polling. 404 means the *server* responded that the endpoint is wrong. The fact the ULR starts with `tst-` suggests you're using a test server that may or may *not* be running the code you assumed. Perhaps you're deploying to IIS using a slow CI/CD pipeline, so while IIS on `tst-bananascorporation.com` is up, there's nothing listening at `tst-bananascorporation.com/SignalRHub` yet. Have you tried hitting the URL directly from the browser?

Comment: Our architecture is mixed architectue. project is based on Framework 4.6.2 and We are using the .netCore libraries and converted the project to Core Project. With startup and program.cs files all.

Comment: Yes I have hit the URL in browser and it is returning string "Connection ID required".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According your description and comment, it sometime works, so I believe there is no code issue in this case.

You can follow the official doc to check the 404 error first.

[Troubleshoot connection errors - Response code 404](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/troubleshoot?view=aspnetcore-7.0#response-code-404)

We can [enable sticky sessions correctly to fix the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/40870#issuecomment-1079498578).

Comment: Those docs are for ASP.NET Core while the OP seems to be using .NET Framework

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Asp.net-core was mentioned in the original tag, and my suggestion should also be used as a direction to continue investigation.

Comment: The tag could be wrong and possibly point to mixed up server and client libraries. ASP.NET Core SignalR was completely redesigned so troubleshooting docs for .NET Core may not help. Besides, the fact the URL starts with `tst-` makes me suspect the web app isn't running yet. Or the wrong server was hit.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I am very familiar with asp.net signalr and asp.net core signalr, we still wait for the op to come back and continue to help him.

Comment: Yes, I am using the Framework 4.6.2 as project framework. But we are using the SignalRCore libraries. 

Can we used mixed architecture here?

Comment: @KishanParmar No, you can’t, you should use .net core if you are using SignalR library